# One sql request for 2 modules. Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I have is two modules, both of which are using similar SQL values. For example both are getting the user avatar, name, registration date and so on. Is it possible to load one module SQL request in to another?

Comment: Possible? Yes. But probably not worth the trouble. If you need to speed things up, there are better, more general approaches to that (bytecode caching, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible. The usual approach to this is to put the common SQL code into a helper class. The first module to call this helper class will actually run the query, and then store the results in a static variable. The second call to this module will just return the contents of that static variable. All you need to make sure is that the second call is actually asking for the same thing (e.g. asking for the *same* avatar, not a different one).

This system is used throughout Joomla itself. Please note that caching large objects will increase the memory requirement, you should limit this to just a few records and columns, and avoid caching TEXT or BLOBs this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a replacement for Hazzit's considerations, just an extension:  so you'd still be using a common helper.

In your module you can build the cache key: thus if you build the same cache key for both modules (based on the user id and a custom string), Joomla will not only cache it throughout the request, but until cache expires.

Also, if the queries spell out identical, they will be cached by mysql as well and not run twice.